# Lightswitch printing an html file - System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Invalid cross-thread access

Tags: printing, visual-studio-lightswitch

I make a new button in Lightswitch and put this code inside to print only a single file:

```
partial void StampaDeposito_Execute()
{
    PrintDocument printInvoice = new PrintDocument();

    printInvoice.PrintPage +=
        new EventHandler<PrintPageEventArgs>(printInvoice_PrintPage);
    printInvoice.Print("TemplateEmail.htm");
} 

void printInvoice_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
    ev.HasMorePages = false;
}
```

but when I click the button following error appears: `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Invalid cross-thread access`.

Is there a workaround to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
using Microsoft.LightSwitch.Threading

partial void StampaDeposito_Execute()
{
    Dispatchers.Main.BeginInvoke(() => {
        PrintDocument printInvoice = new PrintDocument();

        printInvoice.PrintPage +=
            new EventHandler<PrintPageEventArgs>(printInvoice_PrintPage);
        printInvoice.Print("TemplateEmail.htm");
    });

} 

void printInvoice_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
    ev.HasMorePages = false;
}
```

When you get an error about thread access, more often than not you can fix it by invoking the code on the [main dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx).